# Не работает Fragments при пересоздание Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

*При создание активити - все работает как нужно.*

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.set_fragment, OneFragment)
                                .add(R.id.set_fragment, TwoFragment)
                                .hide(TwoFragment).commit();
```

Но, после того, как переворачиваю в альбомный режим

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .attach(OneFragment)
                          .attach(TwoFragment).hide(TwoFragment).commit();
```

Создается вьюшка нормально с **OneFragment** но, перестает работать transaction, а если **TwoFragment**

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .attach(TwoFragment)
                            .attach(OneFragment).hide(OneFragment).commit();
```

Тогда мой кастомный список(TwoFragment) не выводится(при создании активити работает все нормально)

**И не работает другие манипуляции при повороте:**

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.hide(TwoFragment);
                     fragmentTransaction.show(OneFragment);
                     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Кто-то знает может тонкости, которые я не знаю, буду благодарен

Comment: По идее, после пересоздания активити фрагменты все и так на нужных местах и в нужных состояниях и с ними ничего делать больше не надо. Опишите подробнее чего вы хотите добиться и что не получается

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я хочу добиться того, чтобы при повороте фрагменты оставались и была возможность переключаться между ними.
Состояние ихние сохраняется, делаю **attach** , а отображаемый лист пропал. Смотрел объект менеджера фрагментов, все там есть и список есть,но `hind = true` , хотя я и **show** пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилась проблема заменой фрагмента

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace();
```